# Tablesorter : update row number after sort

Tags: jquery, sorting, tablesorter

I have a table with tablesorter.
So if I sort the table, the row numbers are not updated. It is fixed ...

```
$("#tablesorter-demo tr").click(function () {
    $('#tablesorter-demo tr').not(this).removeClass('hilite');
    $(this).toggleClass('hilite');
    var i = $("#tablesorter-demo tr").index(this);
    $("#codefmenims_id").val($("#td_idfmenims" + i + "").text());
    $("#groupe1").val($("#td_gpefme" + i + "").text());
    $("#groupe1s").val($("#td_gpenims" + i + "").text());
});
```

Can someone tell me how I can update the row numbers of my table if I sort table?

Comment: Possibly related to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18763027/jquery-tablesorter-index-column-insert) ~ see [this demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Mottie/4mVfu/1162/)

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#tablesorter-demo tr").each(function(key) {
    $(this).children('td').eq(0).text(key+1);
});
```

Please add a jsfiddle so I can post a better solution.

Comment: Ok you can see it here http://jsfiddle.net/9hHx5/5/ .. Example : So If u click the row 1 you get the information on this row in the input .. if you sort the table when clicking the header(for example Organisme) and you click the the first row of you sort table you got the information of the table before sorting