# Exclude one column from sorting using Tablesorter plugin

Tags: jquery, tablesorter

I am using the tablesorter plugin. I currently have a table consisting of 5 columns. The table sorts on the last column. The first column is the column that I would like to have as fixed. That column is the ranking column. It goes from 1-29, and I would like to keep it as 1-29 in that order. Is there a way to have the first column excluded when sorting occurs? This is the function that I have right now.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#table3").tablesorter({
    sortList: [[4,0]],
    headers: {
        0: {sorter: false},
        4: {sorter: "text"}
    }



});
});
```

I have seen others create classes, and i tried to implement those as well, but with no luck.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/18763027/145346 - try [the demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Mottie/abkNM/9/) - ignore the php portion, just add an extra column of empty cells on the left.

Comment: I have tried using this code as well, and still did not work for me.

Comment: Not sure what I did, still trying to figure it out because my code hasn't change, but i am now able to sort how i want. I relooked at the demo on jsfiddle, and started plugging away at it, and something clicked and worked.

Comment: Please modify that demo and update your question. It is difficult to find the problem with no example.