# Sort table but make one column not to move

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, tablesorter

I want to sort the table below but same time i don't want the numbering column to move, instead it should remain fixed while the other columns move. Any idea on how i should do it

```js
$(document).ready(function() { 
    $("#myTable").tablesorter({ 
        // pass the headers argument and assing a object 
        headers: { 
            // assign the first column not to sort
          
           0: { 
                // disable it by setting the property sorter to false 
                sorter: false 
            }, 
        } 
    }); 
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.tablesorter/2.21.2/js/jquery.tablesorter.min.js"></script>
<link rel='stylesheet' href='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.tablesorter/2.21.2/css/theme.blue.min.css' type='text/css' />
<table id='myTable' cellspacing="1" class="tablesorter-blue">             
    <thead>
        <tr> 
            <th>#</th> 
            <th>last name</th> 
            <th>age</th> 
            <th>total</th> 
            <th>discount</th> 
            <th>date</th> 
        </tr> 
    </thead> 
    <tbody> 
        <tr> 
            <td>1</td> 
            <td>parker</td> 
            <td>28</td> 
            <td>$9.99</td> 
            <td>20%</td> 
            <td>jul 6, 2006 8:14 am</td> 
        </tr> 
        <tr> 
            <td>2</td> 
            <td>hood</td> 
            <td>33</td> 
            <td>$19.99</td> 
            <td>25%</td> 
            <td>dec 10, 2002 5:14 am</td> 
        </tr> 
        <tr> 
            <td>3</td> 
            <td>kent</td> 
            <td>18</td> 
            <td>$15.89</td> 
            <td>44%</td> 
            <td>jan 12, 2003 11:14 am</td> 
        </tr> 
        <tr> 
            <td>4</td> 
            <td>almighty</td> 
            <td>45</td> 
            <td>$153.19</td> 
            <td>44%</td> 
            <td>jan 18, 2001 9:12 am</td> 
        </tr> 
        <tr> 
            <td>5</td> 
            <td>evans</td> 
            <td>22</td> 
            <td>$13.19</td> 
            <td>11%</td> 
            <td>jan 18, 2007 9:12 am</td> 
        </tr> 
    </tbody> 
</table>
```

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18763027/jquery-tablesorter-index-column-insert

Comment: @Mottie you are right with response to the answer that was provided, but the way the other question was asked, someone might not have understood. the question asked just to add an index but did not say it must stay fixed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can bind to the `sortEnd` event and simply write new text to the first column.

The following code takes advantage of the facts that

- jQuery's `.text()` accepts a callback function to calculate and return the new text for each matched element (http://api.jquery.com/text/)
- this callback function receives the (zero-based) element index as first argument, so that you don't need to keep a separate counter variable

```js
$(function() { 
    $("#myTable").tablesorter({ 
        headers: { 
            0: { 
                sorter: false 
            }, 
        } 
    }).on("sortEnd", function () {
        $(this).find('tbody td:first-child').text(function (i) {
            return i + 1;
        });
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.tablesorter/2.21.2/js/jquery.tablesorter.min.js"></script>
<link rel='stylesheet' href='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.tablesorter/2.21.2/css/theme.blue.min.css' type='text/css' />
<table id='myTable' cellspacing="1" class="tablesorter-blue">             
    <thead>
        <tr> 
            <th>#</th> 
            <th>last name</th> 
            <th>age</th> 
            <th>total</th> 
            <th>discount</th> 
            <th>date</th> 
        </tr> 
    </thead> 
    <tbody> 
        <tr> 
            <td>1</td> 
            <td>parker</td> 
            <td>28</td> 
            <td>$9.99</td> 
            <td>20%</td> 
            <td>jul 6, 2006 8:14 am</td> 
        </tr> 
        <tr> 
            <td>2</td> 
            <td>hood</td> 
            <td>33</td> 
            <td>$19.99</td> 
            <td>25%</td> 
            <td>dec 10, 2002 5:14 am</td> 
        </tr> 
        <tr> 
            <td>3</td> 
            <td>kent</td> 
            <td>18</td> 
            <td>$15.89</td> 
            <td>44%</td> 
            <td>jan 12, 2003 11:14 am</td> 
        </tr> 
        <tr> 
            <td>4</td> 
            <td>almighty</td> 
            <td>45</td> 
            <td>$153.19</td> 
            <td>44%</td> 
            <td>jan 18, 2001 9:12 am</td> 
        </tr> 
        <tr> 
            <td>5</td> 
            <td>evans</td> 
            <td>22</td> 
            <td>$13.19</td> 
            <td>11%</td> 
            <td>jan 18, 2007 9:12 am</td> 
        </tr> 
    </tbody> 
</table>
```